# Bloomberg blpapi on Python with remote/server connection

Tags: python, api, bloomberg

I am currently developing a new solution on Python using the Bloomberg api, and it is working very well, however I have to open a Bloomberg terminal each time I want to execute the code otherwise the api is not working. Does someone know if the Bloomberg api can be called on a server (by changing connection settings), instead of a local connection, allowing the code to be executed on airflow for instance instead of having to open Bloomberg every time?

Here is the beginning of my code where the connection settings can be found:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import blpapi
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from optparse import OptionParser

def parseCmdLine():
    parser = OptionParser(description="Retrieve reference data.")
    parser.add_option("-a",
                      "--ip",
                      dest="host",
                      help="server name or IP (default: %default)",
                      metavar="ipAddress",
                      default="localhost")
    parser.add_option("-p",
                      dest="port",
                      type="int",
                      help="server port (default: %default)",
                      metavar="tcpPort",
                      default=8194)

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    return options

def _get_flows_from_bbg(isin:int):
    global options
    options = parseCmdLine()

    # Fill SessionOptions
    sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    sessionOptions.setServerHost(options.host)
    sessionOptions.setServerPort(options.port)

    #print("Connecting to %s:%d" % (options.host, options.port))

    # Create a Session
    session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can connect to what they call SAPI (Server API) - it's a separate subscription.

Comment: Thank you! I will verify if we have access to this subscription!